# Does a WRITE on an OUTPUT file overwrite previous rows?

Tags: cobol

Some thing I don't seem to understand about COBOL, which bothers me, is what happens if a file is opened in `OUTPUT` mode, and there are multiple writes to that file?

For example, for a file named `TEST`:

```
OPEN OUTPUT TEST
WRITE TEST-ROW FROM TEST-ROW-D END-WRITE
WRITE TEST-ROW FROM TEST-ROW-D END-WRITE
```

Will the final `TEST` file have two rows or a single row? I know that opening the file in `OUTPUT` mode sets the file cursor to the beginning, this meaning that the file will be overwritten. But I am not sure if after the second `WRITE` statement, that row would be added as a new one or will overwrite the previous row of the file.

Comment: Every write is a new row. It would be useless otherwise.

Comment: @user207421 thought that I would need to open the file as output and write empty spaces, then reopen it as extend in order to write more rows with the first one replacing all of the previous content

Comment: Well you don’t. That would also be useless. COBOL programmers have better things to do than fight their own file system. And OPEN OUTPUT truncates the file if it exists.

Comment: Why not giving this a try? Either locally, for example with GnuCOBOL, or online, for example at https://godbolt.org/ or https://ideone.com/ ?

Comment: @user207421 Java actually does that. Even after "opening" a file through a BufferedWriter, each call to the `write` method actually replaces the previous file content, without needing to reopen the file.

Comment: @user207421 so I'd probably need to open the file as `WRITE`, write an empty string to it, and then reopen it as `APPEND` and start writing what I need to (in Java)

Comment: Java actually does *not* do that. This is complete and utter nonsense. Cobol’s OPEN OUTPUT or  Java’s`new FileOutputStream()` without the append parameter truncates the file. This is readily observable. Writing spaces to it does not truncate the file, and this is also readily observable: those spaces remain if you then start appending to the file, and they will get in the way when you go to read it. This also is readily observable. You are the victim of a major misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OPEN` only specifies how the file is ... opened. `OUTPUT` means "if it exists, then recreate (empty) at the same place; otherwise create according to the implementor rules" (depending on which COBOL environment you use, there may multiple places).

`WRITE` means "add to the file, error if that isn't possible".

Both ar rules defined in the COBOL standard and handled by every implementor I know (where you can create the file from the COBOL code).

While this information is missing I *assume* that this is about a `SEQUENTIAL` file (either `RECORD SEQUENTIAL` or `LINE SEQUENTIAL`) without a `KEY`.
In this case (if no other error like disk/set full occurs): You will have two identical records in the file afterwards.
Note that these may only be "seen" on disk after `CLOSE` (depending on the cache/flushing done by the implementor/operating system).